# JPA Inheritance/Casting issues

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using the table per class inheritance strategy for my entities. I have a Coach extending the Person class. The coach has a couple of extra attributes, like certification number and certification level.

When I used a maven cargo plugin to generate the tables, it put all the person columns in the player table, so there is a duplication of information, which I wasn't expecting, but that is ok.

I have persisted a person in the database, and now, I want to make that person a coach. How would I do that? I have the id of the person, and the certification number and certification level, but I'm not sure how to add them to the coach table.

Comment: You need to get the person from the database, update it with it's coach attributes, and then use saveOrUpdate.  At least, that's the cliff's notes version of what I think you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "saveOrUpdate"  Is that a specific JPA thing?  Or are you just saying to make sure it's a managed object?